# Navigation Link is taking the whole width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to place an icon in my navigation. I am using **mdbootstrap**. If I do not put any icon, I get the navigation aligned right like so:

[image]

but when I place an image, the links are not aligned any more.

[image]

I think the reason for that when I add an image the navlink occupies the whole space like so in the inspector:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<mdb-navbar
    SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg  scrolling-navbar class z-depth-0"
  >
    <mdb-navbar-brand>
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']">
        <img
          src="../../../assets/imgs/Autosweep-Logo-portrait-hi-res-1.jpg"
          height="100"
          class="d-inline-block align-top"
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    </mdb-navbar-brand>
    <links class="mt-4" style="margin-left: 50px;">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item size-fonts">
          <a
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect
            [routerLink]="['subscribe-now']"
            routerLinkActive="active">
              <img src="../../../assets/imgs/icons/Subscribe 2.png" style="width: 7%; height: 7%;"/>
            <br>
            Subscribe Now
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item size-fonts">
          <a
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect
            [routerLink]="['forms']"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            >
            Forms</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item size-fonts">
          <a
            href="https:www.autosweeprfidapps.com/balanceinquiry"
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect
            >Balance Inquiry</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item size-fonts">
          <a
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect
            [routerLink]="['reloading']"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            >Stations & Reloading Partners</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item size-fonts">
          <a
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect
            [routerLink]="['ada-enrollment']"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            >ADA Re-Activation</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item size-fonts">
          <a
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect
            [routerLink]="['events']"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            >Events</a
          >
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item size-fonts">
          <a
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect
            [routerLink]="['customer-care']"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            >Customer Care</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </links>
  </mdb-navbar>
```

Comment: can you add a snippet from jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I cannot pick the mdbootstrap for the css Sir.

Comment: can you set the image in the background for the list item?

Answer (score 0):

Take the `<br>` out so it would look like this

```
    [routerLink]="['subscribe-now']"
    routerLinkActive="active">
      <img src="../../../assets/imgs/icons/Subscribe 2.png" style="width: 7%; height: 7%;"/>
    Subscribe Now
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I need to place it on top of the word Sir.

Comment: I see. Try shrinking the width and height of picture?

Comment: Try setting navbar width to 100%